# How can I modify categories on a Wikipedia Talk page?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

I was looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_requested_logos and noticed one article already had the logo. So I tried to remove the category from the talk page but couldn't figure out how.

The "categories" option in the UI is greyed out, and there are no categories listed in the talk page source.

Here is an example (though this one doesn't have the logo right now) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:1st_%26_Ten_(1984_TV_series)

How can I remove the logo requested category of a talk page if it's not in the source or in the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The categories option is greyed out because a Talk pages generally don't need categories. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Categorization)

> Every Wikipedia page should belong to at least one category. (However, there is no need to categorize talk pages, redirects, or user pages, though these may be placed in categories where appropriate.)

Look at the [Template:Logo Requested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Logo_requested). You'll see there are several categories and subcategories here. In the case of a TV show you'll likely be looking for `{{tvimage}}` however, it could also be `{{image requested}}` or any other template listed on the template page.

Once you removed the appropriate template the category will be removed as well.